# access public files with google drive

Tags: .net, google-drive-api

I've public files in my google drive account. I want to make a desktop application (.NET) for other users and this application needs read-only access to those public files in my account.
Is this possible with google drive?

i checked the documentation but i found only the following:

1. OAuth2 authentication but if i'm correct this is used to give an application access to the user his own account instead of my account
2. Service account but this is only usable if the program runs on a server i control. Not suitable for a desktop application

Can someone put me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You would use OAuth 2.0 authentication against your account and a [scope](https://developers.google.com/drive/scopes) of:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly

so that your app has read-only access to your Drive files.

Comment: but with readonly scope my PROGRAM has read-only rights. If the user finds - by any way - the credentials(CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET) that are stored in my program, he can make his own program with write access, ... or im i wrong?